# Python -Function - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a small function that should sort alphabetically the degreecheme by last name ("also using first name if the last name for 2 persons are the same ) and I stack into the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

I have never before seen this error, so I have no idea what it means.

```
def degreescheem(listing,x): 
printed=False
temporlist=[]
for i in listing: 
if i[3] == x :temporlist.append(i)
slist=sorted(temporlist,key=lambda s:(s[4],s[5]))
for j in slist :
    informationsformat(j)
    printed = True
if not printed: print("no",x)
```

also it says that the error  here is if i[3] == x :temporlist.append(i) but i cant found out something!!

Comment: What does your `listing` have? How do you call your `degreescheem` function?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are subscripting on a "None" on your error line, which is not a subscriptable type. It needs to by of type list, string, tuple, or some other subscriptable type in Python.

Print out your "i" before the error shows up. It'll help with debugging.